# How do i get the camera object with NEST-API

Tags: javascript, firebase, nest-api

After being authenticated with firebase and my access token to the NEST-API how can i retrieve data from the camera object ? I'm stuck here now...

```
var ref = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
    ref.authWithCustomToken(access_token, function (error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it and it's pretty simple...

```
ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

found it here ->
https://brosteins.com/2014/07/20/beginning-with-the-nest-api/